# Ask the user if they want to do it again

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word 2011 I have a basic macro that prompts the user for input, then formats that input and puts it into the document.  For example:

```
Sub AddNewName()
'
' AddNewName Macro
'
'
    Dim FirstName As String
    FirstName = InputBox("Enter First Name", "")
    Dim LastName As String
    LastName = InputBox("Enter Last Name", "")
    Selection.TypeText Text:="First Name : "
    Selection.TypeText Text:=FirstName
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Last Name : "
    Selection.TypeText Text:=LastName
End Sub
```

I would like it to ask the user at the end: "Another Name? y/n" and if the user answers "y" then start the macro over again.  I've Googled and searched stackoverflow but I either am not using the right search terms or the question just isn't out there already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the code in a loop that breaks if the user clicks "No";

```
do
   Dim FirstName As String
   .
   .
   .

   if (msgbox("Another Name?", vbyesno) = vbno) then exit do
loop
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!  I knew there had to be SOME way to do it, but I couldn't quite figure it out from what I was finding.  It works PERFECTLY.  This is going to make things SO much easier for me and my co-workers.

Comment: Your welcome, you could also just `if FirstName & LastName = "" then exit do` which would mean 2 returns without entering anything would quit the loop.